# Create ESRI ArcSDE Connection File (.sde) using Python/ArcPy at the ArcView license level?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, mxd

Is there an alternative way to create ArcSDE connections in ArcGIS 10.0 using Python at the ArcView license level? I need to create 4 separate connection files for a MXD SDE data source re-point tool.

ArcView licenses are the only available.

The SDE connection files need to be created on-the-fly for each specific user so they can enter their own username and password.

The arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management method is only supported at the ArcEditor/ArcInfo license level.

Comment: At [Use arcpy to connect to database without connection file](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86007/use-arcpy-to-connect-to-database-without-connection-file) in a comment @Luke says this is possible accessing ArcObjects directly (no arcpy), however the specifics are left out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create connection files in every situation. If you already have connections to said databases then you can just use each user's connection file string.

This can be found in database properties. Just copy the name down and then you can do whatever you want.