# Use arcpy to connect to database without connection file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, query-layer, connection

It seems like arcpy can only work with connection files. This creates one of two problems:

1. Deployment requires manual creation of connection files.
2. We have to write a bunch of code to recreate the connection file on each run. (Creating it only the first time is not feasible since the connection information may change.)

As a software developer who does not have access to the production environment, I want to minimize manual steps in the deployment, and I want to keep my code simple. I also want this information to be very easy to change and not require opening up ArcMap (which would be manual), so I want to store it in a simple text config file and establish connections on the fly in my script.

Is there a way to create a connection to a database without creating a connection file? An "in memory only" connection (like is possible with pretty much any other database technology, *even Oracle*, or a number of other libraries, like GDAL)?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2, and I will only be establishing query layers.

Comment: As @Luke noted in comment to an answer, it's possible from Arcobjects. He has an example here: https://code.google.com/p/metageta/source/browse/tools/arcobjectscom.py?r=772

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create temporary connection files through a combination of [the `tempfile` module in the Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) and the [Create Database Connection Geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000016q000000).

Your config file could be read in your script, used to make a temporary connection file, establish your Query Layers, and then delete the connection file.

Comment: I was really hoping to not be tied to the file system at all. That prospect doesn't look very good; does it? one of the reasons I don't like working with ESRI. They make it so hard to develop a clean, simple solution.

Comment: Worth noting that the Create Database Connection tool requires ArcEditor/Standard or ArcInfo/Advanced license levels only and is not available for ArcView/Basic licenses.  A workaround is to create the connection using [ArcObjects via python and comtypes](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80/2856).

Comment: It should be noted that using `tempfile` to actually create the file may be ill-advised. It does a lot of crazy stuff with permissions and visibility of the file and may obtain a write-lock on the file. That may or may not be a problem; I didn't check. I just used `gettempdir()` and made my own file in there and am deleting it in a `finally` block at the end of my program. (I'm also deleting it before creating the connection if it exists, just to be safer.)